# Javacc regular expression that matches all string except certain ones

Tags: regex, javacc

What is the regular expression that'd match **anything** , except these strings:
 `=>`, `|` ?

If you're familiar with javacc, I'm trying to define my `ANYTHING` token as shown below:

```
TOKEN :
{
 <ARROW: "=>" >
|
 <ANYTHING: (["\u0001" - "\uffdc"])+>
|
 <PIPE: "|">
|
 <UPPER_CHAR: (["A"-"Z"])>
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

### Test.jj

```
options {
    STATIC = false ;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Test)
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test parser = new Test(new java.io.StringReader("foo=>bar=baz|done"));
    parser.Parse();
  }
}
PARSER_END(Test)

TOKEN :
{
     < ARROW    : "=>" >
  |  < PIPE     : "|" >
  |  < ANYTHING : (~["=", "|"] | "=" ~[">"])+ >
}

void Parse() : 
{} 
{
  (Any())* <EOF>
}

void Any() :
{Token t;}
{
  ( t=<ARROW>    {System.out.println("ARROW    = '" + t.image + "'");}
  | t=<PIPE>     {System.out.println("PIPE     = '" + t.image + "'");}
  | t=<ANYTHING> {System.out.println("ANYTHING = '" + t.image + "'");}
  )  
}
```

Generate the parser classes:

```
javacc Test.jj
```

and run the `main` method:

```
java Test
```

will print the following for the input `"foo=>bar=baz|done"`:

```
ANYTHING = 'foo'
ARROW    = '=>'
ANYTHING = 'bar=baz'
PIPE     = '|'
ANYTHING = 'done'
```

Comment: Why is the first token in `Any` the `ARROW` ?

Comment: @user1508893, `ARROW` does not need to be the first token.

Comment: Also (as you can easily tell) this is trying to parse a set of CFG. So the RHS has to be an uppercase letter :`<UPPER_CHAR> <ARROW> <ANYTHING> ( | <ANYTHING> )*`

Comment: @user1508893, well, then add a `<UPPER_CHAR>` token. Note that the `<ANYTHING>` cannot start with a capital then, of course!

Comment: @BartKiers: RE "`ARROW` does not .....": Does that mean, `=> B | c` would also be accepted?

Comment: The content of my `Parse()` method would just be `<UPPER_CHAR> <ARROW> <ANYTHING> ( | <ANYTHING> )*` , but for some reason, it didn't work as expected. What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by your last two comments. Also, you seem to be moving your question in the comments here. Your original question, *"anything , except these strings: =>, | ?"*, is answered, right? If you have other questions, I recommend you ask them in a separate question. When posting another question, I urge you to post a proper problem description, since *" it didn't work as expected. What's wrong?"* is unanswerable (far too vague!).

Comment: hm, I guess you're right. I'll drafted up a new question. Thanks, again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18251/discussion-between-user1508893-and-bart-kiers)

Comment: Back to the original problem, I don't think this solution will work when the last character in the file is a '='.

Comment: Also I think it will process ==> as an ANYTHING.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best off to use lexical states.  Here is an RE solution that might work

```
  ("=")+    |     ( ~["=","|"]  |  ("=")* ~["=","|",">"] )+  ("=")*
```

By the way I changed the question a little so that the empty string is not an "anything", so this re should match any string that is not empty and does not contain any "|"s nor any "=>"s.